# Database query count

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I am trying to create a program that will iterate through a data base to match a query for "_75" and set the count to 0 when that match is made. For every records in a database that does not match the query I would like for it to accumulate a negative 1 count. No matter how I try the code I get either the total record count or the total records that match the query.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('p34.db')

c = conn.cursor()
q = "SELECT * FROM 'Pick 3'"
z =  "SELECT * FROM 'Pick 3' WHERE Number LIKE '_75' ORDER BY Draw DESC;"

c.execute (q)
rez = c.fetchall()
count = 0
for row in rez:

if row == rez:
count = 0
else:
count = count -1

print (count)
conn.close()
```

my example for desired results for query _75.

```
record 1 075 count 0
record 2 223 count -1
record 3 228 count -2
record 4 323 count -3
record 5 275 count 0
record 6 888 count -1
```

Comment: Please correct your indentation and, tell us about the problem with your code.

Comment: What does z do? it isn't used in your code

Comment: I tried the code with z initially. q was use for testing. When using z I get the total amount of records that have the string 75 in it. That I not the desired result. I want the program to set the count to 0 when a match is made and count -1 for each record that does not match the string;.

Comment: when I run the code using c.execute(z) I receive the total amount of records that match that query. What I am looking for is the last time the query matches. So if record 1 was 075 and I am at entry record 100  the count should give me -99. This means that the last time a record had the string of *75 was -99 entries ago.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to return a count rather than counting in the python code
For example

```
SELECT COUNT(CustomerID) AS OrdersFromCustomerID7 FROM Orders WHERE CustomerID=7;
```

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp)

Query to count the number of rows where the field is like _75 and also query where fields are not like _75. Take one number from the other. Or just count how many entries are in the table.

Comment: I am actually looking for a reset function. As I iterate through the database and there is a match I want the count to reset 0. Every entry after that would increment -1 until a match is found again. Then it would be reset to 0. Thank you.

Comment: mylist = [1,2,3,4,1,5,1,3,2,4,5,6,7]





for i in mylist:
    if i == 1:
        count = 0
    else:
        count = count -1


print (count)

this code works exactly how i want it to using a list how can i get it to work with a database.

Comment: I found the issue. The iteration was not working because of the () and ,. How do I remove the parenthesis and commas when I execute a query?